# MySQL query to show pets that did not take a certain vaccine?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one table

petVac(pet, vaccine)

the data looks like this:

```
   pet   vaccine
    P1 ​| V1
    P2 | V2 
    P3 | V3
    P1 | V3
    P2 | V4
```

I want to know if a query could be created that would list the pet and vaccine that a pet has not taken yet.

The vaccines listed in the vaccine column are the only available vaccines
so for example, it would result in something like:

```
pet |vaccineNotTaken

P1    V2
P1    V4
P2    V1
P2    V3
P3    V1
P3    V2
P3    V4
```

etc...

I tried doing `select pet, vaccine from petVac where not exists (select distinct pet, vaccine from petVac);` but it results in an empty set. I am confused on how to go about this, is it possible?

Comment: Do you have a list of available vaccines in another table? Because otherwise you won't be able to return rows for vaccines which haven't been applied to any pet yet (because you don't know about them)

Comment: no, but the vaccines listed under the vaccine column are all the vaccines available, I was thinking about using select distinct vaccine in order to get list of vaccines

Comment: What if there's a new vaccine v5 introduced?

Comment: v5 would only be introduced if a pet has gotten that vaccine, but for now, I am just working with the values above and not considering if other vaccines are introduced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a "calendar" table approach to generate sets for all pets and vaccines, we can try:

```
SELECT p.pet, v.vaccine AS vaccineNotTaken
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT pet FROM petVac) p
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT vaccine FROM petVac) v
LEFT JOIN petVac t
    ON t.pet = p.pet AND t.vaccine = v.vaccine
WHERE
    t.pet IS NULL;
```

Here we use a left anti join from the calendar table containing all pet/vaccine combinations to your `petVac` table, retaining only the pairs for which there is no data.